# The various forms of the Sanskrit word 'Para'?

Tags: morphology, sanskrit

I came across the word 'Paratpara' and found the meaning to be 'Greatest of the Great'. This led me to try and understand it in relation with other similar words I already knew - paraspara(mutual) and parampara(tradition)

When I googled, I find:
The root word here is 'para' (beyond)
Some declensions are:
param (superlative of para, meaning 'supreme')
parat (of the supreme?)
paras (of/by the supreme?)

What I struggle to understand is how the sounds(/morphemes?) 'am/as/ath' occur in the words paratpara/paraspara/parampara. Are they declensions or sandhis/conjugations. If so what do they mean?